# Streetview URL on iOS new window

Tags: ios, safari, google-street-view

Given the longitude and latitude, we are able to create a streetview URL like this that works on Desktops and on Android. I'm not using an API.

It does not work on iOS!

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=51.5644804,-0.22777730000007068&cbp=11,0,0,0,0

On iOS, it is this blank page that appears on Safari. (Screenshot)
[image]

Comment: Are you check into real device or simulator?And one more Which IOS version you open?

Comment: Same link open using http://goo.gl/1Phbrg it's working fine,As well as in original device also working fine can you please show your your case?